# Two coroutines write the same term of the slice in parallel. May panic errors occur?

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, slice, goroutine

Two coroutines write the same term of the slice in parallel. May panic errors occur?

I not found document about this.

Concurrent reads and writes only cause data disorder, not happen panic error?

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    arr := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}

    // write 1
    go func() {
        for {
            arr[2] = strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
        }
    }()

    // read 1
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println(arr[2])
        }
    }()

    // write 2
    go func() {
        for {
            arr[2] = strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10)
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    return
}
```

Comment: This is a data race. It will not panic. The result is undefined.

Comment: @BurakSerdar "Undefined" may be a bit of a strong word for it. The [Go memory model](https://go.dev/ref/mem#restrictions) actually has a relatively clear and constrained picture of what may or may not happen during data races (as compared to other languages).

Comment: It used to be "undefined". Looks like things have changed. In this case though, a string is not a single-word object, and it is possible that the read operation may catch an invalid string value that is different from the two writes. If the two writes wrote different lengths, there is a chance that the read will read the shorter byte array with the longer length.

Answer (score -1):

This is a data race. Try running your code using the `-race` flag. e.g. `go run -race main.go`.

Also, here's a nice doc on [Data Race Detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector)